# How to specify project when deploy webapp to Azure via Github action

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions

In all the samples/tutorial I found that show how to deploy a asp.net core (net 6) webapp to Azure via a github action, the website was very easy with a one project/solution.

But how can I specify which project to deploy if my solution has more websites?

In this sample I want to deploy only the frontend (and the referenced .dll/classlibrary domain) and not the backoffice

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- If multiple projects are configured to the same GitHub Repository, by default first project will be deployed.
- To deploy specific project, we need to specify the Project attribute in Azure `application settings`  .
- `App settings` allow you to deploy multiple projects or configure specific project from one repo.
- Initially create an App service in Azure portal.

[image]

- Set the `App settings` for the project which you want to specify
  [image]

> I want to deploy only the frontend (and the referenced .dll/classlibrary domain)

- We need to just reference the class library project in the main Application. The references will be compiled and added as dll's.